# Обмен данными между процессами через UDP на одном хосте

Tags: c++, qt, сеть

Я пытаюсь написать простейшую клиент-серверную игру, используя UDP. В моём приложении есть и сервер и клиент. Некоторые сообщения одинаковы для всех игроков(Расположение врагов, список игроков, счёт игроков) и я отправляю их широковещательными сообщениями. Не удаётся приёма всех сообщений на клиенте и на сервере.

Вот упрощённый пример. В реальности сервер работает в отдельном потоке. Как заставить это работать, чтобы все сообщения (0x01, 0x02, 0x03) были приняты?

main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QNetworkDatagram>
#include <QObject>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

class Server : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QUdpSocket udpSocket;
    QTimer broadCastSendTimer;
    QByteArray rp, broadCastMsg;
private slots:
    void broadCastSendTimer_timeout(){
        udpSocket.writeDatagram(broadCastMsg, QHostAddress::Broadcast, 49152, QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);
    }

    void readPendingDatagrams(){
        static const quint32 broadCastAddr = QHostAddress(QHostAddress::Broadcast).toIPv4Address();
        while (udpSocket.hasPendingDatagrams()) {
            QNetworkDatagram datagram = udpSocket.receiveDatagram();
            if (datagram.destinationAddress().toIPv4Address() != broadCastAddr){
                processDatagram(datagram);
            }
        }
    }
public:
    void processDatagram(QNetworkDatagram &datagram){
        QByteArray msg (datagram.data());
        if (msg.isEmpty()) return;
        if (msg.at(0) == 0x01) {
            qDebug()<<"server: 01 received";
            udpSocket.writeDatagram(datagram.makeReply(rp));
        }
    }

    Server(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent){
        rp.append(0x02);
        broadCastMsg.append(0x03);
        connect(&udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
        connect(&broadCastSendTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(broadCastSendTimer_timeout()));
        udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress::Any, 49152, QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);
        broadCastSendTimer.start(1000);
    }
};

class Client : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QUdpSocket udpSocket;
    QTimer msgSendTimer;
    QByteArray rq;
private slots:
    void msgSendTimer_timeout(){
        udpSocket.writeDatagram(rq, udpSocket.peerAddress(), udpSocket.peerPort());
    }

    void readPendingDatagrams(){
        while (udpSocket.hasPendingDatagrams()) {
            QNetworkDatagram datagram = udpSocket.receiveDatagram();
            processDatagram(datagram);
        }
    }
public:
    void processDatagram(QNetworkDatagram &datagram){
        QByteArray msg (datagram.data());
        if (msg.isEmpty()) return;
        switch (msg.at(0)) {
        case 0x02: {
            qDebug()<<"client: 02 received";
            msgSendTimer.stop();
            break;
        }
        case 0x03: {
            qDebug()<<"client: 03 received";
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    Client(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent){
        rq.append(0x01);
        connect(&udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
        connect(&msgSendTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(msgSendTimer_timeout()));
        udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 49152);
        msgSendTimer.start(1000);
    }
};


#endif // MAIN_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Client client; Q_UNUSED(client)
    Server server; Q_UNUSED(server)
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: В UDP нет гарантии, что пакет будет доставлен. Если сеть чуточку нагрузить, то потеря пакетов будет гарантирована. Или используйте TCP, или делайте перепосылку.

Comment: Дело в том, что здесь пакеты вообще не доставляются. Сервер принимает собственные broadcast пакеты, а клиент их не получает ни одного. Пакеты клиента не доходят до сервера, хотя отправляются. Проблема не в потере пакетов, а в их принципиальной недоставке/неправильной доставке.

Comment: пересмотрел код. клиент слушает только локалхост на своем порту (а не бродакаст). Он принять может только отправленное ему сообщение. В любом случае запускайте wireshark и смотрите. Как минимум поймете, шлют ли они сообщения вообще.

Comment: `setsockopt()` устанавливающий `SO_BROADCAST` для клиентов и сервера где-нибудь в вашем QT делается?

Comment: Как я понял, мне требуется установить SO_REUSEPORT. Осталось выяснить, как это сделать для QUdpSocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось использовать 2 порта. Даже SO_REUSEPORT не помог, т.к. при локальном обмене клиент не принимал персональный (не широковещательный) ответ от сервера, для чего потребовался ещё один сокет с bind address = INADDR_LOOPBACK, но он не смог bind даже в режиме SO_REUSEPORT к уже имеющемуся bind address = INADDR_ANY

```
class Server : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QUdpSocket udpSocket;    
    QTimer broadCastSendTimer;
    QByteArray rp, broadCastMsg;
private slots:
    void broadCastSendTimer_timeout(){
        udpSocket.writeDatagram(broadCastMsg, QHostAddress::Broadcast, 49153);
    }

    void readPendingDatagrams(){
        static const quint32 broadCastAddr = QHostAddress(QHostAddress::Broadcast).toIPv4Address();
        QUdpSocket *pSocket = qobject_cast<QUdpSocket*>(sender());
        while (pSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
            QNetworkDatagram datagram = pSocket->receiveDatagram();
            if (datagram.destinationAddress().toIPv4Address() != broadCastAddr){
                processDatagram(datagram);
            }
        }
    }
public:
    void processDatagram(QNetworkDatagram &datagram){
        QByteArray msg (datagram.data());
        if (msg.size() != 1) return;
        if (msg.at(0) == 0x01) {            
            cout<<"server: 01 received"<<endl;            
            udpSocket.writeDatagram(datagram.makeReply(rp));
        }
    }

    Server(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent){
        rp.append(0x02);
        broadCastMsg.append(0x03);
        connect(&udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));        
        connect(&broadCastSendTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(broadCastSendTimer_timeout()));       

        if (!udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::Any), 49152, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint)){
            cout<<"Server not bound"<<endl;
        }

        broadCastSendTimer.start(3000);
    }
};

class Client : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QUdpSocket udpSocket;
    QUdpSocket udpSocketLocal;
    QTimer msgSendTimer;
    QByteArray rq;
private slots:
    void msgSendTimer_timeout(){
        udpSocket.writeDatagram(rq,  QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost), 49152/* udpSocket.peerPort()*/);
    }

    void readPendingDatagrams(){
        QUdpSocket *pSocket = qobject_cast<QUdpSocket*>(sender());
        while (pSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
            QNetworkDatagram datagram = pSocket->receiveDatagram();
            processDatagram(datagram);
        }
    }
public:
    void processDatagram(QNetworkDatagram &datagram){
        QByteArray msg (datagram.data());
        if (msg.size() != 1) return;
        switch (msg.at(0)) {
        case 0x02: {
            cout<<"client: 02 received"<<endl;
            msgSendTimer.stop();
            break;
        }
        case 0x03: {
            cout<<"client: 03 received"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    Client(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent){
        rq.append(0x01);
        connect(&udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
        connect(&udpSocketLocal, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
        connect(&msgSendTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(msgSendTimer_timeout()));   
        if (!udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::Any), 49153, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint)){
            cout<<"client not bound"<<endl;
        }
        msgSendTimer.start(700);
    }
};
```